Conditionally join to multiple rows
I have two SQL tables TableA and TableB.
TableA :
    AgentID    SEC      CUS
    -------    ----     ------
    22441      138      41332
    53321      59       29296
    89952      282      89011
    68897      297      77654

TableB :
    AgentID    SEC    STAT   NIN
    -------    ----   -----  ------
    22441      138     C     56428
    22441      138           66543
    53321      52      C     77532
    53321      59            87666       
    89952      282     C     00988
    89952      281           87776
    68897      297           11222

I need to join TableA and TableB to get all the columns from TableA and NIN column from TableB. But there are some criteria to join the tables.
TableA and TableB should be join on SEC column. TableA will have one row for one AgentID but TableB can have either one or two. TableA should join only one row of TableB for each AgentID. In TableB first we should look for STAT = C and join this row. If SEC column in TableA and TableB doesn't match for  STAT = C row, then we should join with second row from TableB for same AgentID. If TableB doesn't have two rows for AgentID we can join with any available row for matching AgentID.
For e.g AgentID 22441 have matching SEC value in two rows of TableB but NIN value should come from row of STAT = C but AgentID 53321 doesn't have matching SEC value for STAT = C , so NIN value should come from blank STAT.
Output I am looking for
    AgentID    SEC      CUS     NIN
    -------    ----     ------  ------
    22441      138      41332   56428
    53321      59       29296   87666        
    89952      282      89011   00988
    68897      297      77654   11222

NOTE : I can't use AgentID to join two tables as AgentID for each SEC can be different. So only use SEC to join two tables.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Did you give it a go? What are you stuck on in particular?

Looks like a simple cross apply? select * from tableA a cross apply (select top 1 * from TableB b where b.AgentID = a.AgentID and b.SEC = a.SEC ORDER BY case when stat = 'C' then 0 else 1 end) b

This is a job for the CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 ...ORDER BY ...) pattern (as was already pointed out by siggemannen in comments above).
SELECT A.*, B1.NIN
FROM TableA A
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 B.NIN
    FROM TableB B
    WHERE B.SEC = A.SEC
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN B.STAT = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END  -- Prefer B.STAT = 'C'
) B1

If you need to handle cases where there are no matching TableB rows, you change CROSS APPLY to an OUTER APPLY, which is similar to a LEFT JOIN.
Results:



AgentID
SEC
CUS
NIN




22441
138
41332
56428


53321
59
29296
87666


89952
282
89011
00988


68897
297
77654
11222



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

This looking good. But I just now updated the description in bold NOTE . I can't use AgentID in the join.

@SqlProgrammer - I removed AgentID from match criteria above. Sample results did not change.

Solution:
select A.*, B.MIN
from TableA A
join TableB B
on A.SEC = B.SEC
where B.STAT = 'C' or not exists (
    select 1
    from TableB
    where TableB.AgentID = A.AgentID and TableB.STAT = 'C'
)

Explanation:

we join TableA and TableB as A and B respectively on SEC matching for them
we choose the TableB record whose STAT is either 'C', or there is no match with a STAT of 'C'
we load all columns from A and MIN from B

Alternatively you could use two left joins:
select A.*, COALESCE(B1.MIN, B2.MIN)
from TableA A
left join TableB B1
on A.SEC = B1.SEC and B1.STAT = 'C'
left join TableB B2
on A.SEC = B2.SEC and B2.STAT <> 'C'


It is assumed that there are one or two values in tableB for (AgentId,sec) row in tableA, and only one of them have stat='C'.
So, with 2 JOINs

for stat='C'
for stat<>'C' (is null in example)
take first (with 'C') or other value.

select a.AgentId,a.sec,a.cus,coalesce(b.nin,c.nin) nin
from tableA a
left join tableB b on a.sec=b.sec and b.stat='C'
left join tableB c on c.sec=a.sec and c.stat is null

Output is



AgentId
sec
cus
nin




22441
138
41332
56428


53321
59
29296
87666


89952
282
89011
00988


68897
297
77654
11222



Or common solution with window function
select  a.AgentId,a.sec,a.cus,b.NIN 
from tableA a
left join(
  select *
    ,row_number()over(partition by sec order by stat desc)rn
  from tableB 
  )b on b.sec=a.sec and rn=1

Old version (with AgentId as JOIN condition)
select a.AgentId,a.sec,a.cus,coalesce(b.nin,c.nin) nin
from tableA a
left join tableB b on a.AgentId=b.AgentId and a.sec=b.sec and b.stat='C'
left join tableB c on c.AgentId=a.AgentId and c.sec=a.sec and c.stat is null

fiddle
